# Long e-mail link sent by PHP mailer gets broken

Tags: php, email, url, hyperlink, long-integer

I need to send a very long link using PHP. Known problem: the link is getting broken by the e-mail clients. I've tried it with plain/text or html mails, I put the url in brackets () as proposed in other threads- nothing helps. I know about url shorteners and the possibilty of solving this problem with databases, BUT!!! It IS possible to send links with hundreds of characters; e.g. Ebay does, Amazon does... the link for comfirming the registration from stackoverflow contains more than 250 characters, so?! Looking at the source code of these mails all lines break after 76 characters by default. I've tried to do the same with PHP wordwrap. Result; the source code looks identical, but my links are broken, their links are not! Any ideas? I'd be very glad for help, cause that bothers me!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem on my own. First, the special characters of the link must be encoded (e.g. Thunderbird will now accept the encoded link just like this). Second, set a line-break by default after 76 characters. To avoid that the link gets broken or won't be recognized as a link by the client program anymore, each line needs to end on "=" in order to be recombined...

```
    <?php

    $url = 'http://domainxy.com/index.php';

    $ending = '?var1=gsgsdgsfgdhfjfgj&var2=sdferewerwrr&var3=jghjghjkloozzzz&var4=ghajsldahskhdhriehfsjndfnjnjjfnjsnjdfhksö&var5=öäüöü';
    $ending = utf8_encode($ending);
    $ending = rawurlencode($ending);

    $link = wordwrap( $url . $ending, 75, "=<br />\n", true );

    echo $link;

    ?>

    /* 
    Encodes and devides the link like this:
    http://domainxy.com/index.php%3Fvar1%3Dgsgsdgsfgdhfjfgj%26var2%3Dsdferewerw=
    rr%26var3%3Djghjghjkloozzzz%26var4%3Dghajsldahskhdhriehfsjndfnjnjjfnjsnjdfh=
    ks%C3%B6%26var5%3D%C3%B6%C3%A4%C3%BC%C3%B6%C3%BC
    */
```